# Grabbing the_content from "about us"

Tags: pages

I have created an "about us" page as I am currently in developing for a client's website.

It has a couple of paragraphs, the title & a feature image. What I would like to do is be able to grab all three of them and place them in the home page. How would I go around and do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`get_page_by_title()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_page_by_title/) or [`get_page_by_path()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_page_by_path/) to retrieve page object that will have title and content (which you might need to further process a bit, depending on how complex it is).

And if I remember right [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_the_post_thumbnail/) gives you featured image.